# How to Import Configurable product price with his simple product variant

Tags: import, importexport, dataflow

I want to import configurable product price and his varients.
I created Data Flow profile with following variants...I used sku and price...attribute to export....then after some modification..i import them....but price is coming in backend....but in fronted only configurable product price is coming on all....I want to Update configurable product price  with simple....
my excel sheet image is bellow....
[image]

so i want to know that how to update price of existing product if that is configurable.....with simple variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the element to answer your question here but don't take the extension it is a really, really bad idea... I did it and regret :)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/21805/9489

So, to make it short. Set the lowest price on the configurable product and then use the configurable product to adapt the price following the declinaisons of it.

[This article](https://blog.amasty.com/creating-magento-simple-configurable-products-programmatically/) on amasty'blog is good inspiration.

Comment: thanks for answer..but want to know that is any sequence we have to follow in magento when we update price of configurable product...

Comment: the idea that I was presenting is that you update the price of the configurable product and then you set the price of the attached simple product in function to the configurable...

Comment: what is the necessary field....can you explain your answer with any example ...like which i attached....it will be help full..

Comment: Did you check the blog article I linked my answer to ? The answer is in it...