# Least selling special price should display on configurable product view page

Tags: configurable-product, special-price

please visit this configurable product [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/ship12345.html)

you can see : `MRP : Rs. 9.00, below that Rs. 0.00` by default

**Backend values : Price : 0 , special price : 0**

in same link, above you can see "**color**" dropdown attribute , please select

```
1)Blue, = >  MRP: Rs. 10.00, below that Rs 5.00

2)Light Pink => MRP: Rs. 9.00 below that Rs 4.00

3)choose an option => MRP: Rs. 9.00 ,below that 4.00
```

Now option 3 is working fine. but once you refresh the page **it will show original value entered in backend** in special price

**How Price working :**

Least Price of simple product is displaying once we refresh the page. This is fine.

**how special price working**

Value entered in backend is displaying once we refresh the page. This is not correct.

**What i need is :**

Least special price of simple product should display once we refresh the page

I followed this link answer by @alan for displaying least selling price of simple products : [Magento Configurable Product Price Overriding Simple Product Price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19108/magento-configurable-product-price-overriding-simple-product-price)

```
<?php

#The methods in there have become a bit convoluted, so it could benefit from a tidy,
#...though the logic is not that simple any more.

class OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price
{
    #We don't want to show a separate 'minimal' price for configurable products.
    public function getMinimalPrice($product)
    {
        return $this->getPrice($product);
    }

    public function getMaxPossibleFinalPrice($product) {
        #Indexer calculates max_price, so if this value's been loaded, use it
        $price = $product->getMaxPrice();
        if ($price !== null) {
            return $price;
        }

        $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithHighestPrice($product, "finalPrice");
        #If there aren't any salable child products we return the highest price
        #of all child products, including any ones not currently salable.

        if (!$childProduct) {
            $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithHighestPrice($product, "finalPrice", false);
        }

        if ($childProduct) {
            return $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
        }
        return false;
    }

    #If there aren't any salable child products we return the lowest price
    #of all child products, including any ones not currently salable.
    public function getFinalPrice($qty=null, $product)
{
    //Start edit
    $selectedAttributes = array();
    if ($product->getCustomOption('attributes')) {
        $selectedAttributes = unserialize($product->getCustomOption('attributes')->getValue());
    }
    //End edit
    if (sizeof($selectedAttributes)) return $this->getSimpleProductPrice($qty, $product);

    if (is_null($qty) && !is_null($product->getCalculatedFinalPrice())) {
        return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
    }

    $basePrice = $this->getBasePrice($product, $qty);
    $finalPrice = $basePrice;
    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
    $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');

    $finalPrice += $this->getTotalConfigurableItemsPrice($product, $finalPrice);
    $finalPrice += $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $basePrice) - $basePrice;
    $finalPrice = max(0, $finalPrice);

    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    return $finalPrice;
}

public function getSimpleProductPrice($qty=null, $product)
    {
        $cfgId = $product->getId();
        $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->setStoreFilter($product->getStore(), $product);
        $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
        $selectedAttributes = array();
        if ($product->getCustomOption('attributes')) {
            $selectedAttributes = unserialize($product->getCustomOption('attributes')->getValue());
        }
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $dbMeta = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT main_table.entity_id FROM {$dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product')} `main_table` INNER JOIN
{$dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product_super_link')} `sl` ON sl.parent_id = {$cfgId}
SQL;
        foreach($selectedAttributes as $attributeId => $optionId) {
            $alias = "a{$attributeId}";
            $sql .= ' INNER JOIN ' . $dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product') . "_int" . " $alias ON $alias.entity_id = main_table.entity_id AND $alias.attribute_id = $attributeId AND $alias.value = $optionId AND $alias.entity_id = sl.product_id";
        }
        $id = $db->fetchOne($sql);
        return Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id)->getFinalPrice($qty);
    }

    public function getPrice($product)
    {
        #Just return indexed_price, if it's been fetched already
        #(which it will have been for collections, but not on product page)
        $price = $product->getIndexedPrice();
        if ($price !== null) {
            return $price;
        }

        $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, "finalPrice");
        #If there aren't any salable child products we return the lowest price
        #of all child products, including any ones not currently salable.
        if (!$childProduct) {
            $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, "finalPrice", false);
        }

        if ($childProduct) {
            return $childProduct->getPrice();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getChildProducts($product, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        static $childrenCache = array();
        $cacheKey = $product->getId() . ':' . $checkSalable;

        if (isset($childrenCache[$cacheKey])) {
            return $childrenCache[$cacheKey];
        }

        $childProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductCollection($product);
        $childProducts->addAttributeToSelect(array('price', 'special_price', 'status', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date'));

        if ($checkSalable) {
            $salableChildProducts = array();
            foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
                if($childProduct->isSalable()) {
                    $salableChildProducts[] = $childProduct;
                }
            }
            $childProducts = $salableChildProducts;
        }

        $childrenCache[$cacheKey] = $childProducts;
        return $childProducts;
    }

/*
    public function getLowestChildPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable);
        if ($childProduct) {
            if ($priceType == "finalPrice") {
                $childPrice = $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
            } else {
                $childPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
            }
        } else {
            $childPrice = false;
        }
        return $childPrice;
    }
*/
    #Could no doubt add highest/lowest as param to save 2 near-identical functions
    public function getChildProductWithHighestPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        $childProducts = $this->getChildProducts($product, $checkSalable);
        if (count($childProducts) == 0) { #If config product has no children
            return false;
        }
        $maxPrice = 0;
        $maxProd = false;
        foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            if ($priceType == "finalPrice") {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
            } else {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
            }
            if($thisPrice > $maxPrice) {
                $maxPrice = $thisPrice;
                $maxProd = $childProduct;
            }
        }
        return $maxProd;
    }

    public function getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        $childProducts = $this->getChildProducts($product, $checkSalable);
        if (count($childProducts) == 0) { #If config product has no children
            return false;
        }
        $minPrice = PHP_INT_MAX;
        $minProd = false;
        foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            if ($priceType == "finalPrice") {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
            } else {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
            }
            if($thisPrice < $minPrice) {
                $minPrice = $thisPrice;
                $minProd = $childProduct;
            }
        }
        return $minProd;
    }

    //Force tier pricing to be empty for configurable products:
    public function getTierPrice($qty=null, $product)
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I can see in description of Alan's code there is such phrase: **this solution DOES NOT display pricing on the product page itself**.

Comment: just answered on the linked question. HTH!

Comment: Please use this extension
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Comment: i am using that extension also. it helped to display in cart page, but in product view page i want to display special price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a configurable product it doesn't matter what's the price of simple products -- these prices are ignored completely. So if you want to sell a simple product A which has price $29.99 and a simple product B ($39.99) then you must create a configurable product, set its price to $29.99 and open Associated product tab. Add products you want to associate with this configurable product. After adding them a block named Super product attributes configuration appears which contains options and price differences. Leave product A price empty and put 10 (+$10) to product B price field and voila: different simple product have different price.

There's actually an extension that allows you to use simple product prices instead of price differences, but it's kind of tricky to set up. Since it's free extension, I hope nobody complains about me pasting its link here:

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

OR

Try This if your problem solve

```
<?php 
  if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
  $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
  $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
  foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
    echo $simple_product->getSku() . " - " . $simple_product->getName() . " - " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . "<br>";
}
endif;
```

Comment: i am using this extension for displaying price in cart page. but it did't worked for view page . for displaying simple products prices in view page i used code in question. but i want to display the special price of simple products in view page. please give me the code for that

Comment: you said "but i want to display the special price of simple product.", there simple product means simple product of configurable product or simply simple product?

Comment: simple products of configurable products

Comment: check my answer I  edit it. check if it works for you

Comment: i placed your code in at the end of price.php file as like : http://pastebin.com/cjmk1ZqB please check and tell whether i placed code  in right file and right place.

Comment: i am getting error as [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html)

Comment: there are  syntax error in app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php on line 216   check line no 216 there are some problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36052/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-shakir-khan).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but involve a lot of mods, for the sake of discusion I'll referer directly to the "core" code and leave up to you to make a custom module.

In the product details page the price information for child product are stored in 
a javascript object called optionPrice

```
 var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice( .....
```

This object was written into the page by the following design file
design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

The information written in the optionsPrice object is used in the configurable.js that in the function "reloadPrice" update the page writing the proper price infos.

In order to display also the special price I suggest the following:

1) Add to the optionsPrice the special price information modifing the getJsonConfig function.

2) Modifiy the configurable.js file to update the page.

The configurable.js file refer to a "price-clone" that is a copy of the price box that is duplicated on the configurable product page...

I hope to put you in the proper direction for the development !

Comment: i will check and let you know.....

Comment: please give me the complete code to display the special prices of simple products.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

#The methods in there have become a bit convoluted, so it could benefit from a tidy,
#...though the logic is not that simple any more.

class OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price
{
    #We don't want to show a separate 'minimal' price for configurable products.
    public function getMinimalPrice($product)
    {
        return $this->getPrice($product);
    }

    public function getMaxPossibleFinalPrice($product) {
        #Indexer calculates max_price, so if this value's been loaded, use it
        $price = $product->getMaxPrice();
        if ($price !== null) {
            return $price;
        }

        $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithHighestPrice($product, "finalPrice");
        #If there aren't any salable child products we return the highest price
        #of all child products, including any ones not currently salable.

        if (!$childProduct) {
            $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithHighestPrice($product, "finalPrice", false);
        }

        if ($childProduct) {
            return $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
        }
        return false;
    }

    #If there aren't any salable child products we return the lowest price
    #of all child products, including any ones not currently salable.
    public function getFinalPrice($qty=null, $product)
{
    //Start edit
    $selectedAttributes = array();
    if ($product->getCustomOption('attributes')) {
        $selectedAttributes = unserialize($product->getCustomOption('attributes')->getValue());
    }
    //End edit
    if (sizeof($selectedAttributes)) return $this->getSimpleProductPrice($qty, $product);

    if (is_null($qty) && !is_null($product->getCalculatedFinalPrice())) {
        return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
    }

    $basePrice = $this->getBasePrice($product, $qty);
    $finalPrice = $basePrice;
    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
    $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');

    $finalPrice += $this->getTotalConfigurableItemsPrice($product, $finalPrice);
    $finalPrice += $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $basePrice) - $basePrice;
    $finalPrice = max(0, $finalPrice);

    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    return $finalPrice;
}

public function getSimpleProductPrice($qty=null, $product)
    {
        $cfgId = $product->getId();
        $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->setStoreFilter($product->getStore(), $product);
        $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
        $selectedAttributes = array();
        if ($product->getCustomOption('attributes')) {
            $selectedAttributes = unserialize($product->getCustomOption('attributes')->getValue());
        }
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $dbMeta = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT main_table.entity_id FROM {$dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product')} `main_table` INNER JOIN
{$dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product_super_link')} `sl` ON sl.parent_id = {$cfgId}
SQL;
        foreach($selectedAttributes as $attributeId => $optionId) {
            $alias = "a{$attributeId}";
            $sql .= ' INNER JOIN ' . $dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product') . "_int" . " $alias ON $alias.entity_id = main_table.entity_id AND $alias.attribute_id = $attributeId AND $alias.value = $optionId AND $alias.entity_id = sl.product_id";
        }
        $id = $db->fetchOne($sql);
        return Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id)->getFinalPrice($qty);
    }

    public function getPrice($product)
    {
        #Just return indexed_price, if it's been fetched already
        #(which it will have been for collections, but not on product page)
        $price = $product->getIndexedPrice();
        if ($price !== null) {
            return $price;
        }

        $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, "finalPrice");
        #If there aren't any salable child products we return the lowest price
        #of all child products, including any ones not currently salable.
        if (!$childProduct) {
            $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, "finalPrice", false);
        }

        if ($childProduct) {
            return $childProduct->getPrice();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getChildProducts($product, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        static $childrenCache = array();
        $cacheKey = $product->getId() . ':' . $checkSalable;

        if (isset($childrenCache[$cacheKey])) {
            return $childrenCache[$cacheKey];
        }

        $childProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductCollection($product);
        $childProducts->addAttributeToSelect(array('price', 'special_price', 'status', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date'));

        if ($checkSalable) {
            $salableChildProducts = array();
            foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
                if($childProduct->isSalable()) {
                    $salableChildProducts[] = $childProduct;
                }
            }
            $childProducts = $salableChildProducts;
        }

        $childrenCache[$cacheKey] = $childProducts;
        return $childProducts;
    }

/*
    public function getLowestChildPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        $childProduct = $this->getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable);
        if ($childProduct) {
            if ($priceType == "finalPrice") {
                $childPrice = $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
            } else {
                $childPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
            }
        } else {
            $childPrice = false;
        }
        return $childPrice;
    }
*/
    #Could no doubt add highest/lowest as param to save 2 near-identical functions
    public function getChildProductWithHighestPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        $childProducts = $this->getChildProducts($product, $checkSalable);
        if (count($childProducts) == 0) { #If config product has no children
            return false;
        }
        $maxPrice = 0;
        $maxProd = false;
        foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            if ($priceType == "finalPrice") {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
            } else {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
            }
            if($thisPrice > $maxPrice) {
                $maxPrice = $thisPrice;
                $maxProd = $childProduct;
            }
        }
        return $maxProd;
    }

    public function getChildProductWithLowestPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        $childProducts = $this->getChildProducts($product, $checkSalable);
        if (count($childProducts) == 0) { #If config product has no children
            return false;
        }
        $minPrice = PHP_INT_MAX;
        $minProd = false;
        foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            if ($priceType == "finalPrice") {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
            } else {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
            }
            if($thisPrice < $minPrice) {
                $minPrice = $thisPrice;
                $minProd = $childProduct;
            }
        }
        return $minProd;
    }


    public function getChildProductWithLowestSpecialPrice($product, $priceType, $checkSalable=true)
    {
        $childProducts = $this->getChildProducts($product, $checkSalable);
        if (count($childProducts) == 0) { #If config product has no children
            return false;
        }
        $minPrice = PHP_INT_MAX;
        $minProd = false;
        foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            if ($priceType == "finalPrice") {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getFinalPrice();
            } else {
                $thisPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
            }
            if($thisPrice < $minPrice) {
                $minPrice = $thisPrice;
                $minProd = $childProduct;
            }
        }
        return $minProd;
    }

    //Force tier pricing to be empty for configurable products:
    public function getTierPrice($qty=null, $product)
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same result